# R^3 Triangle inequality norm

Tags: normed-spaces, functional-inequalities

Let's define norm in $\mathbb{R}^3$ $$ ‖x‖ = \sqrt{x_1 ^2 + 2x_2 ^2 + 3x_3 ^2}$$
How can I solve triangle inequality $||x + y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$.
I did:
$$||x+y|| = \sqrt{(x_1 + y_1)^2 + 2(x_2 + y_2)^2 + 3(x_3 + y_3)^2}$$
and I don't know how to get $$\sqrt{x_1 ^2 + 2x_2 ^2 + 3x_3 ^2} + \sqrt{y_1 ^2 + 2y_2 ^2 + 3y_3 ^2}$$
Can you help me solve this? Or maybe this is seminorm?

Comment: Use that for any vector $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, $\|x\|=\|f(x)\|_2$, where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the usual euclidean norm, and $f$ is the linear map defined by $f(x)=(x_1,\sqrt2x_2,\sqrt3x_3)$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Anne Bauval suggested to you,
$\|x+y\|=\|f(x+y)\|_2=\|f(x)+f(y)\|_2\leq\|f(x)\|_2+\|f(y)\|_2$ because $\|.\|_2$ is a norm.

And I'll let you conclude and possibly add an argument that I would have implied.

Comment: So can I just write $\sqrt{(x_1 + y_1 )^2 + 2(x_2 + y_2)^2 + 3(x_3 + y_3)^2} \leq \sqrt{x_1 ^2 + y_1 ^2 + 2x_2 ^2 + 2y_2 ^2 + 3x_3 ^2 + 3y_3 ^2)}$ or I need something to add between this two roots?

Comment: $\sqrt{(x_1 + y_1 )^2 + 2(x_2 + y_2)^2 + 3(x_3 + y_3)^2} \leq \sqrt{x_1 ^2 + 2x_2 ^2  + 3x_3 ^2 }+ \sqrt{y_1^2+2y_2^2+3y_3 ^2}$